# Convert stream to object?

Tags: c#

Newbie question for you. I have the following code. I get an error because a object has to be passed to ClientRequest. But am unsure how pass the stream as a object.

`TcpClient _client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();

NetworkStream _clientStream = _client.GetStream();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ClientRequest, _clientStream);`

Thanks

Comment: please add the code, or at least the signature, for ClientRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that code as long as ClientRequest is declared like so:

```
public void ClientRequest(Object state) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably *not* that you can't pass the stream as an object -- Everything in .net is an object, so casting to object (which is a "widening" conversion, and thus doesn't need to be specified) shouldn't be an issue.

My guess is your ClientRequest is expecting to be passed a NetworkStream or something, which it's not going to get -- it's going to get an object, which you'll then need to cast to a NetworkStream in order to use it properly.

Comment: Basically I want to pass the networksteam to the ClientRequest function to read and write to the client. But the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem will only let me pass an object.
<code>
void ClientRequest(object request)
      {

          byte[] response = ObjectToByteArray(request);
          Console.WriteLine("\nClients request:\n{0}\n", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(request));

      }
</code>

Im new to this so bare with me :)

Comment: @arbme: right.  You can only pass an object.  But *everything* is an object, so you should be able to pass anything you like.  The trick is, in your function, you want to cast it back into what you know it is -- like, `NetworkStream ns = (NetworkStream) request;`, and work with `ns` instead of `request` in your case.

Comment: @arbme: Also, you seem a bit confused about whether you're passing a stream or a byte array or....something else.  Perhaps the cast will help you straighten that out.